# Android POST JSon object to the server

Tags: android

I am trying to send a some data along with a base64 image by creating  object and trying to send it to the server but i am getting a ThreadPoolExecutor error. i am not getting what to do now. Here is my code for the activity.
Please Suggest me what should i do

```
    package com.vethics.freewifi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txt_fullname, txt_email, txt_phone, txt_birthday, txt_gender;
    private RadioGroup radioGrp;
    private RadioButton radioBtn;
    public Person person;
    String encodedImage;
    Context mcontext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        mcontext = RegistrationActivity.this;
        txt_fullname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_fullname);
        txt_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        txt_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_phone);
        txt_birthday = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_birthday);
        radioGrp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        int selectOptId = radioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioBtn = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectOptId);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_logo);
        // then this imageString pass to json object
        encodedImage = ConvertBitmapToBase64Format(bitmap);
        /*
         * Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), encodedImage,
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
         */

        // check if you are connected or not
        if (isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Internet Connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    public void backFunction(View abc) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void doneFunction(View abc) {

        if (!validate()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Thread going", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
        new InsertThread().execute("http://www.gochhattisgarh.in/api/register.php");

    }

    public String ConvertBitmapToBase64Format(Bitmap bitmap)

    {

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream);
        byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
        // get the base 64 string
        String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        return imageString;

    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private boolean validate() {
        if (txt_fullname.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (txt_email.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (txt_phone.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (txt_birthday.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if (encodedImage.toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        /*else if (radioBtn.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;*/

        else
            return true;
    }

    public class InsertThread extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            person = new Person();
            person.setUsername(txt_fullname.getText().toString());
            person.setEmail(txt_email.getText().toString());
            person.setPhone(txt_phone.getText().toString());
            person.setBirthday(txt_birthday.getText().toString());
            person.setGender(txt_gender.getText().toString());
            person.setImageFile(encodedImage.toString());

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("username", person.getUsername());
                jsonObject.put("email", person.getEmail());
                jsonObject.put("phone", person.getPhone());
                jsonObject.put("birthday", person.getBirthday());
                jsonObject.put("gender", person.getGender());
                jsonObject.put("ImageFile", person.getImageFile());
            } 

            catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();


            return makeRequest(urls[0], json);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
        }
    }



    public static String makeRequest(String uri,String data) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String result = null;
        try {

            //Connect 
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(uri).openConnection()));
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.connect();

            //Write
            OutputStream outputStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(data);
            writer.close();
            outputStream.close();

            //Read
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```